# Using ARR how do you rewrite a url if a cookie is missing?

Tags: asp.net, iis, arr

I know I can rewrite a url based on values from a cookie using the `{HTTP_COOKIE}` variable in the conditions part of the rule. This rule grabs a cookie called ServerProxy and does a rewrite to that server url.

```
<rule name="SendTrafficToServerProxyCookieValue" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="ServerProxy=(.*)" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

If the `ServerProxy` cookie is absent or unset I would like to direct the traffic to an authentication server called `authenticate.app`. How do I write a rewrite rule that will do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rule name="SendTrafficToServerProxyCookieValue" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="ServerProxy=(.+)" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
<rule name="DoAuthRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="SOMETHING_ELSE" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="ServerProxy=(.+)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Note that `*` have been changed to `+` to make sure that cookie is not empty. Negate simply flips condition, so makes it empty or non-existant.